# jquery: run code on first use of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to run a piece of code that stores values of a form into a db every xxxx seconds, this should only run if a user is using the form for the first time so I wanted to use a basic focus event for this, this works but this means that every time a user focus on a field the code will run(again), but not after the xxxx seconds.

So I need a way that if a user started using the form it should run the setInterval function every xxxx seconds and not everytime a user focused on a field.

// basic example

```
$('form').on('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //run code into db
        alert('saved');
    },10000);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) :

```
$('form').one('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //run code into db
        alert('saved');
    },10000);
});
```

but this would execute one time per element, so I'm afraid the best solution isn't so glamour :

```
$('form').one('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function(){
    if ($(this.form).data('done')) return;
    $(this.form).data('done', 'yes');
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //run code into db
        alert('saved');
    },10000);
});
```

or :

```
var doit = function() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //run code into db
        alert('saved');
    },10000);
    $('form').off('focus', 'input, textarea, select', doit);
};
$('form').on('focus', 'input, textarea, select', doit);
```